# Boolean functions satisfying a condition

Tags: boolean-algebra

What is the total number of Boolean functions $f :\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{1,-1\}$ such that

\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{e}
\sum_xf(x)f(x+y) = 0
\end{equation}

for all $0\neq y$?

Is there some closed form construction to obtain them all? Or even one specific example if it exists at all? I tried to use inverse Fourier transform but no luck.

For $n = 2$ one such example is $f(00) = f(10) = f(01) = 1$ and $f(11) = -1$. But for larger $n$ it seems very difficult.

Note that $f$ cannot be additive.

**EDIT:** Alex below claims that no such functions exist for $n >2$. However, for $n =4$, I was able to construct (very ad-hoc) the following

Columns 1 through 14

```
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
 0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
 1    -1     1     1     1     1    -1     1     1     1     1    -1     1    -1
```

Columns 15 through 16

```
 1     1
 1     1
 1     1
 0     1
-1    -1
```

One way to to think of this is by considering the function $f_y: x \mapsto f(x)f(x+y)$ and impose that $f_y$ is additive for all $y$. So the question now becomes:

**Question:** Does there exist $\hat{y}$ such that $f_y = \chi_{\hat{y}}: x\mapsto (-1)^{\hat{y}x^T}$.

Then \eqref{e} becomes a simple consequence of characters.

Comment: Your $n=4$ example does not look right. For $y \,in \{2, 6, 10\}$ the sum is not $0$.

Comment: Well, I manually checked $y = 2 = 0010$ and the sum is zero. o not sure what's going on.

Comment: Might be a misunderstanding on my side. Could you run (or look at) the check code, I added to my answer?

Comment: The discrepancy between @AxelKemper and original poster's view is in the meaning of the "plus" sign in $f(x+y)$. It seems Axel's answer is treating it as usual addition of numbers modulo $2^n$, while the question is treating the arguments as binary vectors of length $n$ so their addition is component-wise modulo $2$ (i.e. 0001+0001 = 0000 rather than 0010).

Comment: @PeterKošinár: So, the "plus" is in fact an "xor"?

Comment: You're looking for the number of [bent functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_function)

Comment: @HarryWest Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to find solutions using the `Python` interface of Microsoft's [Z3 solver](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki/Using-Z3Py-on-Windows).

My `Z3PY` model:

```
from z3 import *

n = 2
noOfMinterms = 2 << (n-1)

print("n = %s" % n)
print("minterm rows = %s" % noOfMinterms)

Minterms = [i for i in range(noOfMinterms)]

#  define truth table with one Bool variable for every row
table = []

for i in Minterms:
    table += [Bool("b" + str(i))]

def f(x):
    return If(table[x % noOfMinterms], 1, -1) 

s = Solver()

for y in range(1, noOfMinterms):
    s.add(Sum([Product(f(x), f(x + y)) for x in Minterms]) == 0)

solutions = 0

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    solutions += 1
    print(str(solutions) + ": ", [" 1 " if is_true(m[table[i]]) else "-1 " for i in Minterms])
    #  prevent the solution to be found again
    s.add(Or([table[i] != m[table[i]] for i in Minterms]))

if solutions == 0 :
    print("No solutions found. Sorry")
else:
    print("Solutions: %s" % solutions)
```

Output for $n = 2$:

```
n = 2
minterm rows = 4
1:  [' 1 ', '-1 ', ' 1 ', ' 1 ']
2:  ['-1 ', ' 1 ', ' 1 ', ' 1 ']
3:  [' 1 ', '-1 ', '-1 ', '-1 ']
4:  [' 1 ', ' 1 ', ' 1 ', '-1 ']
5:  [' 1 ', ' 1 ', '-1 ', ' 1 ']
6:  ['-1 ', ' 1 ', '-1 ', '-1 ']
7:  ['-1 ', '-1 ', ' 1 ', '-1 ']
8:  ['-1 ', '-1 ', '-1 ', ' 1 ']
Solutions: 8
```

The solution mentioned in the question is number $4$ of the $8$ solutions.

For $n$ larger than $2$, no solution was found.

---

[MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) also does not find solutions for $n \gt 2$:

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n = 2;
int: noOfMinterms = pow(2, n);
set of int: Minterms = 0 .. noOfMinterms - 1;

array[Minterms] of var bool: X; %  true = 1; false = -1

constraint  
forall(y in Minterms where y != 0) (
   sum([f(x) * f(x+y) | x in Minterms]) == 0
);

function var int: f(int: x) = if X[x mod noOfMinterms] then 1 else -1 endif;
  
function int: f2(Minterms: x) = if fix(X[x]) then 1 else -1 endif;

solve satisfy;

output ["\(n): "] ++
       [show_int(3, f2(i)) | i in Minterms];
```

---

Check code in `C#` for given solutions:

```
int n = 4;
int noOfMinterms = (2 << (n - 1));
int[] f = { 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 };

for (int y = 1; y < noOfMinterms; y++)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < noOfMinterms; x++)
    {
       sum += f[x] * f[(x + y) % noOfMinterms];
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{y} {sum}");
}
```

Comment: @Alex Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Peter Košinár's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/77812/peter-ko%C5%A1in%C3%A1r) comment, I modified my `Z3` model to use bit-wise exclusive or for $x+y$ rather than addition modulo $2$:

```
from z3 import *

n = 4
noOfMinterms = 2 << (n-1)

print("n = %s" % n)
print("minterm rows = %s" % noOfMinterms)

Minterms = [i for i in range(noOfMinterms)]

#  define truth table with one Bool variable for every row
table = []

for i in Minterms:
    table += [Bool("b" + str(i))]

def f(x):
    return If(table[x], 1, -1) 

s = Solver()

for y in range(1, noOfMinterms):
    s.add(Sum([Product(f(x), f(x ^ y)) for x in Minterms]) == 0)

solutions = 0

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    solutions += 1
    print(str(solutions) + ": ", [" 1 " if is_true(m[table[i]]) else "-1 " for i in Minterms])
    #  prevent the solution to be found again
    s.add(Or([table[i] != m[table[i]] for i in Minterms]))

if solutions == 0 :
    print("No solutions found. Sorry")
else:
    print("Solutions: %s" % solutions)
```

The numbers of solutions for small $n$:

```
n   # Solutions
2      8
3      0
4      896
5      ?
```

---

The modified [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) model:

```
include "globals.mzn";

int: n = 4;
set of int: Bits = 0 .. n;

%  pre-calculate powers of 2: 1, 2, 4, ...
array[Bits] of int: twopow = array1d(Bits, [pow(2, i) | i in Bits]);

int: noOfMinterms = twopow[n];
set of int: Minterms = 0 .. noOfMinterms - 1;


array[Minterms] of var bool: X; %  true = 1; false = -1

constraint  
forall(y in Minterms where y != 0) (
   sum([f(x) * f(bitxor(x, y)) | x in Minterms]) == 0
);

%  function to calculate the biwise xor of two ints
%  cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR
function int: bitxor(Minterms: x, Minterms: y) =
  sum([twopow[i] * (((x div twopow[i]) + (y div twopow[i])) mod 2) | i in Bits]);
  
function var int: f(int: x) = if X[x] then 1 else -1 endif;
  
function int: f2(Minterms: x) = if fix(X[x]) then 1 else -1 endif;

solve satisfy;

output ["\(n): "] ++
       [show_int(3, f2(i)) | i in Minterms];
```

---

The modified check code in `C#` which confirms the example solution from the question:

```
int n = 4;
int noOfMinterms = (2 << (n - 1));
int[] f = { 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1 };

for (int y = 1; y < noOfMinterms; y++)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < noOfMinterms; x++)
    {
        sum += f[x] * f[(x ^ y) % noOfMinterms];
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{y} {sum}");
}
```